# Replace or Strip a specific character between two characters in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

replace a specific character between two characters in javascript using regex

My specific requirement is

i want to replace single quote between double quotes.

Ex: sdadads'sdasdads"this is the 'quote"   -->    sdadads'sdasdads"this is the quote"

i tried

```
`sdadads'sdasdads"this is the 'quote"`.replace(/\"[^\']\"/g, 'replaced')
```

but the output is

`sdadads'sdasdadsreplaced`

Comment: Can there be multiple single quotes inside `"..."?

Comment: Yes there can be multiple single quotes,  i want to remove all single quotes between double quotes.

Comment: What do you do when you encounter this `asdf"asdf"d'asdf'asdf"` ?

Comment: I have structured data so it will never be my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this [`.replace` with a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var str = `"this 'is 'the 'quote"`

var repl = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function($0) { 
           return $0.replace(/'/g, ""); });

console.log(repl);
//=> "this is the quote"
```

- Using a simple regex to match `"..."` string using negated character class
- Inside the function we remove all single quotes

Comment: Thank you brother, thank you very much it works but i needed the regex thing which i got in another answer.

Comment: abhinav you are stripping of the double quotes also

Comment: oh yes, fixed it now

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hey just asking whether you know there is a proper way to parse django variable to json.

Comment: I am facing a lot of issues parsing django variable to json i have tried safe and escapejs filters but still get issues while parsing it.

Comment: I don't know `djongo` but, you can take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573747/parsing-json-fields-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the double quotes itself and what is in between the double quotes in a capturing group. Then use a replacement function where you replace all the single quotes in the second capturing group with an empty string

```
(")([^"]+)(")
```

```js
let str = `sdadads'sdasdads"this is the 'quote"`;
let res = str.replace(/(")([^"]+)(")/g, function(_, g1, g2, g3) {
  return g1 + g2.replace("'", "") + g3;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I would imagine it's because this only handles one single quote.  Also, why did you replace single quotes with 'replace'?  The question is clearly about _removing_ single quotes.

Comment: buddy i want to strip that single quote between double quotes only can you help

Comment: Exactly what i was looking it to be thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: Actually there is no need of any capture groups. Moreover `.replace("'", "")` will replace only one single quote.

Comment: @anubhava You are right, much easier if you replace on the full match.

Answer (score 1):

Variable width negative lookbehind is not permitted in Javascript, so you may use \K operator to find if a `'` is between two double quotes or not using this regex,

```
"[^']*\K'(?=[^']*")
```

**Explanation:**

- `"` --> Matches a double quote
- `[^']*` --> Matches zero or more characters anything except a single quote
- `\K` --> Resets whatever matched so far
- `'` --> Matches a literal single quote
- `(?=[^']*")` --> Look ahead ensuring there is a double quote after zero or more any characters except a single quote

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9V8z96/1)**

Comment: Bht Bht Dhanyawad bhai, bht der se nhi mil rha tha.

Comment: There is no `\K` in Javascript. This is PCRE feature

Comment: Sorry my bad... It just slipped my mind that \K doesn't work for JS. Please select Anubhava's answer as accepted one.

Comment: Thank you very much